# Micronaut with rabbit mq sending the message from producer to consumer, on consumer side it accept the same value in parameter

Tags: java, rabbitmq, micronaut, micronaut-rabbitmq

Using rabbitMQ with Micronaut latest version. On consumer both the parameter accepts the same value from the producer, however, I am sending the different value from the producer.

Output of consumer, since the value for `categoryId` and `id` are same

[image]

On the producer side I am sending the different value as below

```
  @RabbitProperty(name = "replyTo", value = "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to")
    @Binding(ConstantValues.COUNT_SUB_CATEGORY)
    Maybe<Long> Count(@MessageHeader String categoryId, String id);
```

[image]

The `categoryId` and `id` have a different value in the producer side

What is the mistake I am doing quite not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange. I replicated this issue on my system too. And, this issue seems to go away when deprecated `io.micronaut.messaging.annotation.Header` is used.

Can you try that on your code too and see if it works ?

Your new code:

Producer:

```
@Binding(ConstantValues.COUNT_SUB_CATEGORY)
Maybe<Long> Count(@Header String categoryId, String id);
```

Consumer:

```
@Queue(......)
Long count(@Header("categoryId") String categoryId, String id) {
    ......
}
```

Tested using micronaut version 2.5.1, micronaut-rabbitmq 2.5.0, java 11

Comment: Well this is not working for me with micronaut 2.5.5 java 16 you can check on this repo https://github.com/anandjaisy/micronautRabbitMq and I have filled an issue here https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-rabbitmq/issues/241

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been fixed in this https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/5588